# ScrollView.ContentSize not updating on Android with dynamic content within nested grid

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this set up on a page:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <!-- static content -->
            <ContentView x:Name="ConditionalView"/>
            <!-- static content -->
            <Grid/> <!-- populated from an items source -->
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
<ContentView.Content>
```

In most cases the "conditional view" is never shown, but when it is it's content is set to:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Some static elements -->
    <Grid x:Name="Favourite_Books"/> 
    <!-- Some static elements -->
    <Grid x:Name="Favourite_Songs"/>
</Grid>
```

The 2 grids "Favourite Books" and "Favourite Songs" can have items added and removed, this is all done in the code behind like so:

```
// A book/song is added by clicking a button in the static elements 
// above the respective grid. There is also a "delete" button in the
// row for a book/song that removes that instance from the source list.
//
private void BuildBooks(List<Book> books)
{
    int row;
    
    // Unsubscribe from button click events.
    foreach (var child in Favourite_Books.Children)
    {
        if (child is Button b)
            b.Clicked -= DeleteBook;
    }
    Favourite_Books.Children.Clear();
    Favourite_Books.RowDefinitions.Clear();
    
    row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
    {
        Favourite_Books.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        var bookLabel = new Label() { Text = books[i].Title };
        SetRow(bookLabel, row);
        Favourite_Books.Children.Add(bookLabel);
        //
        var bookButton = new Button() { BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent };
        bookButton.BindingContext = books[i];
        bookButton.Clicked += DeleteBook;
        SetRow(bookButton, row);
        Favourite_Books.Children.Add(bookButton);
        row++;
        //
        if (i < books.Count - 1)
        {
            Favourite_Books.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 1 });
            var divider = new BoxView() { BackgroundColour = Color.Black };
            SetRow(divider, row);
            Favourite_Books.Children.Add(divider);
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

When items are added (or removed), the ContentSize of the ScrollView isn't updated; the content will end up running off the bottom of the page without letting you scroll to see it all. This issue only arises on Android (tested on a Samsung tablet), the same code works fine on Windows.

I've attempted calling ForceLayout on the Grids and the ScrollView, but this doesn't fix it. I can get the Bounds of the Grid holding the 2 dynamic grids to update to what it should be, but the ScrollView doesn't take notice. Using nested grids like this isn't great I realise, probably moving the entire setup to a BindableLayout would be the best answer, but is there any way to handle this so it works on Android without rewriting it all?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more details about the adding and removing? I need more code to reproduce. And have you try to test on another device? Does it display the same contentsize?

Comment: I've only been able to test this on a Samsung tablet and a Windows desktop, the issue only shows on the Android device.